# Edit Report before sending to printer in devexpress XtraReports Suite

Tags: printing, devexpress, report

I have an problem,I want to show end-user a kind of form with colorful background in report preview page and when he/she decides to pint it because I have printed that background on papers before I want to remove background and sent it to printer.Somehow background is already printed on papers and I just fill some spaces on it(for example name,and etc.) 
If I want to remove background at first end user just sees some texts on spread on a with paper and it is not so user friendly,
Do you have any suggestions what I should do?
thanks a lot
here is the code that I use for showing print preview

```
            DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport report;

            report = new Parvane_report();
            report.Parameters[0].Value = "";
            report.Parameters[1].Value = parvane.Registration_date;
            report.Parameters[2].Value = parvane.Senf_number;
            report.Parameters[3].Value = parvane.Contex;
            report.Parameters[4].Value = parvane.Title;
            report.Parameters[5].Value = "";
            report.Parameters[6].Value = parvane.Name;
            report.Parameters[7].Value = parvane.Family;
            report.Parameters[8].Value = parvane.Sodor;
            report.Parameters[9].Value = parvane.Tavalod;
            report.Parameters[10].Value = parvane.Shenasname;
            report.Parameters[11].Value =parvane.CodMeli;
            report.Parameters[12].Value =parvane.Ostan;
            report.Parameters[13].Value =parvane.Shahrestan;
            report.Parameters[14].Value =parvane.Shahr;
            report.Parameters[15].Value =parvane.Bakhsh;
            report.Parameters[16].Value =parvane.Dehestan;
            report.Parameters[17].Value =parvane.Rosta;
            report.Parameters[18].Value =parvane.CodPosti;
            report.Parameters[19].Value =parvane.Adress;
            report.Parameters[20].Value =parvane.Codshaghel;




            using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report))
            {
                // Invoke the Ribbon Print Preview form modally, 
                // and load the report document into it.
                printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();

                // Invoke the Ribbon Print Preview form
                // with the specified look and feel setting.
               // printTool.ShowRibbonPreview(UserLookAndFeel.Default);
            }
```

but as I said I want to show the end user a preview with background and remove background when used clicked print button,
If you know any other solutions into my problam please help me with it..
I forgot to say that I am using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`XtraReport.Watermark`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_Watermarktopic) property to set background of report. Before printing you need to set [`ReportPrintTool.PrintingSystem.Watermark.ImageTransparency`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingDrawingPageWatermark_ImageTransparencytopic) property [`ReportPrintTool.PrintingSystem.Watermark.TextTransparency`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingDrawingPageWatermark_TextTransparencytopic) property to 255 and restore theese values after printing. For this you need to use `ICommandHandler` interface as described [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2571), handle `PrintingSystemCommand.Print` command and `PrintingSystemCommand.PrintDirect` command, and hide `PrintingSystemCommand.Watermark` command from users.
Here is example:

```cs
public class PrintWithoutWatermarkCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    private readonly ReportPrintTool _reportPrintTool;
    private bool _isExecuted;

    public PrintWithoutWatermarkCommandHandler(ReportPrintTool reportPrintTool)
    {
        _reportPrintTool = reportPrintTool;

        //Hide watermark command from users.
        _reportPrintTool.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.Watermark, CommandVisibility.None);
    }

    public virtual void HandleCommand(PrintingSystemCommand command, object[] args, IPrintControl control, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (_isExecuted || !CanHandleCommand(command, control)) return;

        var printingSystem = _reportPrintTool.PrintingSystem;

        var watermark = printingSystem.Watermark;

        var imageTransparency = watermark.ImageTransparency;
        var textTransparency = watermark.TextTransparency;

        //Hide watermark.
        watermark.ImageTransparency = 255;
        watermark.TextTransparency = 255;

        if (command == PrintingSystemCommand.Print)
            _reportPrintTool.PrintDialog();
        else
            try
            {
                _isExecuted = true;

                printingSystem.ExecCommand(command);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuted = false;
            }

        //Restore watermark.
        watermark.ImageTransparency = imageTransparency;
        watermark.TextTransparency = textTransparency;

        handled = true;
    }

    public virtual bool CanHandleCommand(PrintingSystemCommand command, IPrintControl control)
    {
        return command == PrintingSystemCommand.Print || command == PrintingSystemCommand.PrintDirect;
    }
}
```

And now you can use this command handler in your code:

```cs
report = new Parvane_report();

//Your code
//Add watermark here if you have not added it before.

using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report))
{
    printTool.PrintingSystem.AddCommandHandler(new PrintWithoutWatermarkCommandHandler(printTool));

    printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
}
```

Comment: Woww..Thank you so much..It works great.But when it finishes printing the print preview updates and is without any watermark..Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @MajidHojati I'm using DevExpress 14.1.5 and I have no such problems. Try to use `printTool.PrintingSystem.EndPrint` event to restore watermark transparency or try to close preview after print.

Comment: Thanks For your help..How can I close preview after print?is there any close property for printtool?or sth like that?

Comment: @MajidHojati You can use this: `printTool.PrintingSystem.ExecCommand(PrintingSystemCommand.ClosePreview)`.

Comment: Thank you so much.I upgraded to 14.1 version and I still have that problem.I'll try to use the code that you gave me..thanks

Comment: I tried the code and it does not close preview and it remains blank just after hitting print button..Could this caused by parameters?I have 3 parameters in print preview dialog

Comment: This behavior seems strange to me. Parameters shall not affect the closing of the print preview.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It was my mistake..I used that code in wrong place.Now it works great ..I have another question,Do you have any suggestions about putting text in right place and when we print it,it places in its location.For example I have a pre-printed paper with a field such as "Name:" how do I manage to put the name (for example John Smith) in print form that when user prints it on  that paper it became Name:John Smith..

Comment: @MajidHojati Try to use [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument16128/PreprintedForm) article. Go to the «Supply a Pre-Printed Form» section.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me. Thanks!  I also had the problem of the watermark disappearing after I printed the document.  In my case this was fixed by setting the "ShowPrintMarginsWarning" to False for the XTRAREPORT.  I was getting a margins warning dialog and somehow that interfered with the watermark.

If anyone should want the VB.NET code for the above C# code it is below.

```
Option Infer On

Imports DevExpress.XtraReports.UI


Public Class PrintWithoutWatermarkCommandHandler
Implements ICommandHandler

Private ReadOnly _reportPrintTool As ReportPrintTool
Private _isExecuted As Boolean

Public Sub New(ByVal reportPrintTool As ReportPrintTool)
    _reportPrintTool = reportPrintTool

    'Hide watermark command from users.
    _reportPrintTool.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.Watermark, CommandVisibility.None)
End Sub


Public Function ICommandHandler_CanHandleCommand(ByVal command As PrintingSystemCommand, ByVal printControl As IPrintControl) As Boolean Implements ICommandHandler.CanHandleCommand
    Return command = PrintingSystemCommand.Print OrElse command = PrintingSystemCommand.PrintDirect

End Function

Public Sub ICommandHandler_HandleCommand(ByVal command As PrintingSystemCommand, ByVal args As Object(), ByVal printControl As IPrintControl,
                                         ByRef handled As Boolean) Implements ICommandHandler.HandleCommand
    If _isExecuted OrElse Not ICommandHandler_CanHandleCommand(command, printControl) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim printingSystem = _reportPrintTool.PrintingSystem

    Dim watermark = printingSystem.Watermark

    Dim imageTransparency = watermark.ImageTransparency
    Dim textTransparency = watermark.TextTransparency

    'Hide watermark.
    watermark.ImageTransparency = 255
    watermark.TextTransparency = 255

    If command = PrintingSystemCommand.Print Then
        _reportPrintTool.PrintDialog()
    Else
        Try
            _isExecuted = True

            printingSystem.ExecCommand(command)
        Finally
            _isExecuted = False
        End Try
    End If

    'Restore watermark.
    watermark.ImageTransparency = imageTransparency
    watermark.TextTransparency = textTransparency

    handled = True

End Sub
```

End Class